# How can I use wp_ajax_response for front-end error reporting?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

I already have the wp hook code in place, and now I want to send error messages back to the front end to be placed in alert box or html element.

```
//my plugin  
add_action('wp_ajax_track_upload', 'track_upload');

function track_upload() {
  (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    //report error to front end
    // i.e. send ajax response
  }
}

// my front end form
<form method="post" action="
<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=musistic_track_upload' )?>"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" accept="audio/*">
  <input type="submit" value="upload audio" name="submit"
  id="submit_to_your_elders">
</form>
```

What's missing now? Do I need a js file to do some ajax handling?
I read the codex article https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Ajax_Response, but it does not explicitly demonstrate how to tie in the wp_ajax_resonse in. How do I send a retrieve such a response? A code example relevant to my specific circumstance would greatly help a visual learner such as myself.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to do something like this as Error Reporting. When something goes wrong - in the PHP function - set an Error Header that will return back to your JQuery along with a string message:

```
header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 Empty Attachment' );
echo 'Could Not Upload File.';
exit;
```

To classify this as an `error` header you need `HTTP/1.1 400` but after that you may put any kind of text. [Here's a list of response codes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php). Then on your `$.ajax().fail()` function you can display those errors in a meaningful way:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action      : 'your_function_hook_thing',
        some_data   : some_kind_of_data
    },
    dataType: 'text'
} )
.success( function( data ) {
    /* You win! */
} )
.fail( function( data ) {
    /* You lose, show error */
    console.log( data.responseText );
    console.log( 'Request failed: ' + data.statusText );
} );
```

The `data.responseText` is what you echo and the `data.StatusText` is going to be what you decided to add into the `header()` function in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your comment McGee. I actually have some specific error cases in mind also, such as when the uploaded audio file doesn't have a supported file extension or the file size is beyond the cap. Could I report these errors using this method?

Comment: @KeenanDiggs You would run your logic to test against your specific cases ( such as file type and size ) and when it's `false` ( or something to tell you it's incorrect ) you would change the echo message and the header message ( minus the `HTTP/1.1 400` which is an error response ) and finally `exit` so your function doesn't continue to run.